# how to get back on intranet's default.aspx from internet's default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, intranet

First let clear my scenario: I have a website on public ip IIS residing in a city (say city A) and another IIS running locally residing in a City B.

Now, my website is running on City B's IIS and fetching data from local server is working fine. On the other hand the City A's IIS website is working and fetching the data from their local database server.

on City B server I have created a default.aspx page which have two linkbutton which say click this to see city B data and click this to see city A data.

so, when user click on city B linkbutton then the webpages run on their local, but when user click on city A linkbutton then via internet the city B peoples can view the data of City A.

So far so good, but on web pages their is button named as go to Main, so as city B accessing the web pages of City A and click on Main button then it showing the city A's default.aspx page.

So, my question is that, is there a way that my site can rectify that from where the page have been redirected and when main button click on either side it must see and show their own default.aspx pages.

I hope I am able to express my scenario. if not then please you may see the diagram, which may clear you what I am asking for.

```
http://202.61.43.37/html/Doc1.html
```

looking forward to your early and kind response

Regards

M.A.Bamboat

Answer (score 1):

If user is on City B site and clicks on link button to go to City A site, than pass a parameter in query string to tell Site A that it is coming from Site B.

If site A is a single page site than you can check the query string and if value exists, than on clicking Main send user to site B Main other wise site A Main.

If there are more than one pages than keep it in session that user has come from other site and you have to send him back to that site, I hope you understood what I am trying to say.